# How to say that one has some "time reserve"?

Tags: phrase-request

One can say:

> No hurry. We have plenty of time.

But this implies having lots of time.

What if I would like to say, that *we have just some reserve of time* — it's not *plenty*, so we can't relax and at the same time there is no need to hurry — just keep a regular tempo.

There is a word *leeway*, but I don't believe it's an answer to my question.

I found another word — *sufficient time margin*, but still doesn't sound like the best option.

Comment: There are lots of ways you *could* express this, but without a specific context it's hard to recommend one, as I don't think there is a universal term for it. But you could say things like "We have some time, but not a lot", or "We don't have a lot of extra time", or "We do have some extra time"

Comment: "We have enough time" or "We have just enough time", maybe.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a word leeway, but I don't believe it's an answer to my
>   question.

Correct, leeway is not the right word.  Leeway is defined as "the amount of freedom to move or act that is available" and is a noun which is often applied to signify a specific movement.  For example, the deadline is 15th August but we have 2 days leeway either side.

> Found another one — sufficient time margin, but still doesn't sound
>   like the best option.

Agreed, this can be used, but is very formal and sounds like something in a legal document or a report.

> No hurry. We have plenty of time.

Does indeed imply that one can sit back and do nothing because there is plenty of time.

I would use phrases like

- This is not the top of the list but does need to be addressed soon
- This is important but can wait for a short time
- We do have some time to spare but please stay on this and report progress
- We have sufficient time to ensure we do a thorough job
- We have bought some time in the short term
- This is not urgent but does need to be looked at in the near term

It would also help to be specific, for example,

- This is urgent (how urgent, what is the impact?)
- This needs to be done in the next 2 weeks (what is the timeframe?)

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically we don't say *we have just some reserve of time*. We say...

> [*We [do] have **some** time **in hand***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we%20have%20some%20time%20in%20hand%22)
>
> **in hand** *- ready for use if required; in reserve*
>   (definition 22.2, [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hand))

Note that OP's ***just*** doesn't work in such contexts, but including optional ***some*** in the expression implies that although there's not *much* additional time available, it will probably be *enough*. You could be more explicit with, say, *We have **a little** time in hand*, but in practice ***some*** implies the same.

Optional ***do*** above adds a degree of emphatic assertion (and/or refutation, if the speaker is countering someone else's opinion that the goal *can't* be achieved in the available time).